# What is the advantage of CFB over OFB?

Tags: aes, symmetric, stream-cipher, cfb, ofb

I was wondering if CFB can be better than OFB in any ways. I would like to know in what cases one would use CFB over OFB.

Comment: They're both silly; there's no reason to use either one instead of CTR, and while you're at it, you should be using an authenticator, and generally use an authenticated encryption scheme.  AES-GCM is an example; crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305 is another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reason I can imagine why one would prefer CFB over OFB or CTR is **error propagation**. Another [reason may be technical issues with the relieability of the transmission line](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20183).

This comes from the fact that if you flip a single bit in an OFB ciphertext then you only get the same bit flipped in the underlying plaintext. But if you flip a single bit in CFB mode, you get the bit flipped in the plaintext *and* get the following block to decrypt to gibberish. So there's a larger chance of you detecting a manipulation of the ciphertext because the effect on the plaintext is bigger.

*However* the above reason stems from the dark ages of cryptography, where *authenticated encryption* was usually done ad-hoc or not at all, so people actually relied on these error propagation properties. These days, using anything but CTR is pointless, because CTR allows very nicely for SIMD parallelization and error propagation as a property is kinda irrelevant because the authentication tag will catch any modifications.

Comment: Addition: CFB has a drawback worth mention compared to OFB: a collision of ciphertext blocks leads to a potentially exploitable relation for the plaintext blocks that follow (their XOR is also the XOR of the ciphertext blocks that follow), and is observable if it occurs. This becomes an issue for mere gigabytes of data for 64-bit block ciphers (like 3DES, [Gost](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5830)..). There's a comparable issue with CBC. By contrast, OFB remain secure for a petabyte, as long as the key is not used for multiple IVs. CTR brings several further improvements.

Comment: But OFB & CBC are self recovering/ synchronization modes, whereas CTR/ OFB will not decrypt correctly if a block is lost during transmission?

Comment: @crypt in any modern system, where you employ some form of proper authentication beyond hoping for error propagation, you also can't handle a lost block because you can't verify the data as untampered. So the self-recovery for the synchronization doesn't matter there. However, I could see extremely niche scenarios where potentially tampered-with data is preferable over having to retransmit a whole packet. In those situations, self-recovering encryption modes might indeed be preferable over CTR/OFB.

Answer (score 2):

Advantages of **CFB** over **OFB**:

1. Ability to parallel decryption, and hence it has better performance.
2. Ability to random read access during decryption. There is no need to calculate all previous (expensive) steps to decrypt some part of information.
3. Presence of error propagation, though it lasts only for some parts of the message. In my opinion, it's not a big advantage.

Advantages of **OFB** over **CFB**:

1. Ability to calculate almost all the work in advance and perform only xor with cipher text.
2. Absence of error propagation.